# Docker for Windows failed build is no longer showing intermittent images

Tags: windows, docker

Last last year I upgraded my local Windows 10 **Docker for Windows** install to `2.x` with `WSL 2` integration. I noticed that the build output was modified to a large extent. I am now having trouble debugging failed builds because *it seems* like the intermittent layers/images are not being created anymore.

**I am sure that last statement is inaccurate but I just cannot seem to find them anymore.**

After executing a build (straight up `docker builder -f Dockerfile .`), I see the following output

```
[+] Building 12.6s (17/19)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine                                   0.0s
 => [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  9.8s
 => => transferring context: 4.26MB                                                                                9.7s
 => [base 1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [base 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [base 3/4] RUN apk update                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [base 4/4] RUN apk add icu-libs                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/7] RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/he  0.0s
 => CACHED [build 4/7] COPY . .                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [build 5/7] WORKDIR /src/Sso.Host                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [build 6/7] RUN dotnet restore -s https://some-host/nuget/v3/index.  0.0s
 => ERROR [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app                                             2.7s
------
 > [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app:
#17 0.562 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
#17 0.562 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
#17 0.562
...
#17 2.644 IdentityProviders/Local/LocalApi.cs(122,33): error CS0117: 'Constants' does not contain a definition for 'Errors_InvalidSubjectChangeRequest' [/src/SsoExtensions/SsoExtensions.csproj]
#17 2.644 IdentityProviders/Local/LocalApi.cs(434,27): error CS0117: 'Constants' does not contain a definition for 'Provider_Local' [/src/SsoExtensions/SsoExtensions.csproj]
#17 2.644 IdentityProviders/Local/LocalApi.cs(445,33): error CS0117: 'Constants' does not contain a definition for 'Errors_FailedAuditCapture' [/src/SsoExtensions/SsoExtensions.csproj]
#17 2.668
#17 2.668 Build FAILED.
#17 2.668
...
#17 2.668 IdentityProviders/Local/LocalApi.cs(122,33): error CS0117: 'Constants' does not contain a definition for 'Errors_InvalidSubjectChangeRequest' [/src/SsoExtensions/SsoExtensions.csproj]
#17 2.668 IdentityProviders/Local/LocalApi.cs(434,27): error CS0117: 'Constants' does not contain a definition for 'Provider_Local' [/src/SsoExtensions/SsoExtensions.csproj]
#17 2.668 IdentityProviders/Local/LocalApi.cs(445,33): error CS0117: 'Constants' does not contain a definition for 'Errors_FailedAuditCapture' [/src/SsoExtensions/SsoExtensions.csproj]
#17 2.669     6 Warning(s)
#17 2.669     5 Error(s)
#17 2.669
#17 2.669 Time Elapsed 00:00:02.04
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app]: exit code: 1
```

As you can see, it has failed. My desire is to run the previous image to see where/why it is failing but when I execute the following command `docker image ls -a`, the only output is

```
REPOSITORY                             TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet   3.1-alpine   39b66f5a7b54   3 weeks ago   105MB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk      3.1-buster   52a3845cafb1   3 weeks ago   710MB
```

There are no containers running based on the following commands -- `docker container ls -a` and `docker ps -a` and output

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

And the build output above, which *used* to show the Id of the intermittent layers/images no longer does.

In case this was a version `2.x` thing, I upgraded my local install to `3.1` but I am seeing the same results. I have also followed other postings about where these images could be located at -- C:\ProgramData\Docker, C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop, C:\Users\username\AppData\Local, etc. but I am not seeing anything and unsure why that would help anyways since the `docker` commands are not showing them.

Unsure if it makes a difference but as I mentioned, I am running Windows 10 Enterprise with WSL 2 integration and using the Ubuntu distro.